# How to get a users reputation ranking/position?

Tags: support, reputation

Using the SO API request `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/{userId}`, I can get a user's current reputation score with no problems. What I'd like to know is where the user's rank in the set of all the Stack Overflow's users is; for example, "the top 10%," or alternatively "the position 18,415 out of 520,546." Ideally, I'd like to be able to get this for various time periods: for all the time, the last month, the last year.

Is this possible?